# I'm getting 404 error when trying to load css

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm just started using codeigniter and I'm having difficult time understanding why browser cannot render or load js file and css files.

Inside my view I'm successfully render source

```
 <title></title>
     <script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
```

And using FTP client I notice that there is Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.js file on public_html folder.

When I try to manually retrieve that js from browser I'm getting 404 error.

?

My .htaccess file content is

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your Rewrite cond to the below mentioned,

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|Scripts|css|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

In the above rule we are re writing all the urls of the `http://domainName.com/home` to `http://domainName.com/index.php/home` except those which are having images,Scripts,css,robots.txt in there url request URI, so by adding Script in the rewritecond, we are by-passing all the urls with  http://domainName.com/Script to go to codeigniter index.php

Answer (score 2):

Your htaccess says to route anything but the following to index.php/$1:

```
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
```

So just add Scripts and css directories to that statement:

```
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|Scripts|css|images|robots\.txt)
```